# How do I stop overwriting info in excel (Java/Selenium)

Tags: java, excel, selenium

I'm trying to record the time from page start until a specific thing is displayed and write that time into an excel file and then do it again for x times.  Right now I am able to do it each time through the loop it is overwriting everything and I am only ending up with the last result.  The other problem is that it's not putting the info where I expected it to put it.  I just want all of the results in the first column.  I've been banging my head against this one for days trying all the options I found in SO with varying success but never getting the result I've been shooting for.  Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.time.StopWatch;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
// Revert back to here
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CreationHelper;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;

public class PageLoadTimer {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Set Browser Location
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "/Users/mackro/Desktop/Java Workspace/BrowserDrivers/chromedriver");

    // Create object of SimpleDateFormat class and decide the format
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");

    // get current date time with Date()
    Date date = new Date();

    // Now format the date
    String date1 = dateFormat.format(date);

    // Start Loop
    int i = 0;
    while (i <= 2) {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        // Start timer
        StopWatch pageLoad = new StopWatch();
        pageLoad.start();
        // Go to URL & skip basic auth
        driver.get("https://www.godaddy.com/");

        // Wait for cookies to be displayed or 10 seconds then

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Cookies")));
        pageLoad.stop();

        // Get the time
        long pageLoadTime_ms = pageLoad.getTime();
        long pageLoadTime_Seconds = pageLoadTime_ms / 1000;
        driver.close();

        // put the time in an excel file
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(
                    "/Users/mackro/Desktop/Java Workspace/Data Tables/" + date1 + ".xls");

            Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
            CreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
            org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Page Load Times");

            Row row1 = sheet.createRow((short) 0);
            // inserting first row cell value
            row1.createCell(i).setCellValue(createHelper.createRichTextString("Time " + pageLoadTime_ms));

            workbook.write(fileOut);
            workbook.close();
            fileOut.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {

            fnfe.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {

            ioe.printStackTrace();

        }
        i++;

    }
    System.out.println("results recorded");
}

{

}
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but in your code you are looping twice and for each iteration you are opening / writing / and closing the xls file

Comment: I am asking how to fix two problems. 1) how do I stop overwriting my results and 2) how can i get the results to line up in col 1.  I'm quite new to this so I'm cobbling things together and trying to figure it out.  Unfortunately I'm not good enough with this yet to be able to troubleshoot each problem I come across and sometimes can't figure out what specifically I need to search for to find the answer to my question. And I have poured through as much as I could find on overwriting in excel and writing  when everything is null (which I finally figured out)

Comment: Your code always to create sheet every time.  If the sheet exists, read out all exists rows and append new row.  Then write all rows back to sheet.   From my previous experience of apache poi.jar which to read and write excel, it not support append new row to exist sheet, like we did to append string to a plain text file.  I'm not sure the latest poi support that now.

Comment: as @yong pointed out your sheet is getting created for every iteration, so best way to go about is either use an existing sheet and keep adding data to that or create sheet only in first iteration and then use the same in other iterations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first iteration of while loop you need to create the workbook and in the following iteration you can use the same one created in first iteration. try as following:

```
    int i = 0;
while (i <= 2) {
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    // Start timer
    StopWatch pageLoad = new StopWatch();
    pageLoad.start();
    // Go to URL & skip basic auth
    driver.get("https://www.godaddy.com/");

    // Wait for cookies to be displayed or 10 seconds then

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Cookies")));
    pageLoad.stop();

    // Get the time
    long pageLoadTime_ms = pageLoad.getTime();
    long pageLoadTime_Seconds = pageLoadTime_ms / 1000;
    driver.close();

    try {
        HSSFWorkbook workbook;
        Sheet sheet;

        if(i==0) {
             workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
            sheet = workbook.createSheet("Page Load Times");

        }
        else {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/Users/mackro/Desktop/Java Workspace/Data Tables/" + date1 + ".xls");
            workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
            sheet = workbook.getSheet("Page Load Times");

        }

        Row row = sheet.createRow(i);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
        cell.setCellValue(pageLoadTime_ms);

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/Users/mackro/Desktop/Java Workspace/Data Tables/" + date1 + ".xls");
        workbook.write(fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        workbook.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {

        fnfe.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {

        ioe.printStackTrace();

    }

        i++;
    }
```

Comment: wow kushal, thank you and everyone else so much.  having this working has helped me greatly.